# Cannot find any serverlessrepo* permissions in my AWS permissions policies list

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless

When I try to use serverless on AWS, under my 'normal' account, I get a permissions error:

```
User: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:user/x is not authorized to
perform: serverlessrepo:ListApplications on resource: 
arn:aws:serverlessrepo:eu-west-2:xxx:applications/*
```

But when I log in as my 'admin' user, and go to modify permissions, I can't see any 'serverlessrepo' permissions in the policies/groups/direct permissions etc:

[image]

Where is the `serverlessrepo:ListApplications` permissions policy?

Comment: I don't see a managed policy for enabling this permission. What I would recommend is going to your IAM User and add (create) inline policy. In the next screen, under Service, search for `Serverless Application Repository`. Once you select the service, under the List action you will see ListApplications. Create the inline policy and retry your command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IAM user permissions need to include an Allow statement for CodeDeploy:ListApplications.

The administrator access managed policy (arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess) already includes it.

Go to AWS Console > IAM > Access management > Users > click on your user > check your permissions.

If you want to add the ListApplications permission to your user, Click on "Add permissions" and choose a policy that contains that permission (for example, AWSCodeDeployReadOnlyAccess). Alternatively, you can create a permissions policy document of your own.